# batch file is giving unexpected error

Tags: windows, batch-file, scripting, cmd

After 5 to 6 time continuously execution of bat file I have received fallowing error -
"Input line is too long and The syntax of the command is incorrect"

```
@call "c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" x86_amd64;

@call "c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\bin\vcvars32.bat" x86_amd64;

@set INCLUDE=%INCLUDE%;"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include";

@set BIT64=-DSOLARIS_64bit

@set DDK5_ROOT=c:\WinDDK\7600.16385.1

@set DDK_ROOT=c:\WinDDK\7600.16385.1

@set DDKDRIVE=C:

@set VERSION=/DBUILD_MAJOR_VERSION="4" /DBUILD_MINOR_VERSION="2" /DBUILD_REVISION="1.3"

@set ENCRYPT=__SSL_SUPPORT__

@set RES_BUILD_DEBUG=1

@set Platform=platform-win32.4.00
```

Comment: Not an expert, but a variable set in the command prompt stays until the prompt is closed, if you continuously run that won't `INCLUDE` be set to `;"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include";;"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include";;"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include";;"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include";;"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include";;"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include";;"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include";;"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include";;` ?

Comment: Is there any solution to avoid this

Comment: The easiest would be having the batch file that sets the variables outside of the repeating one

Answer (score 0):

No idea or indication what `vcvarsall.bat` and `vcvars32.bat` do.

```
@set INCLUDE=%INCLUDE%;"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include";
```

will extend `include` every time if you are executing this procedure within a loop. This *may* be the problem, but it should take more than `5 or 6` times.

Beginning the procedure with `@echo off` would mean you could remove the `@` at the start of each line.

You could find where the error is occurring by inserting a `pause` statement at strategic points (say, before and after the setting of `include`) and you could observe the precise command that would be executed by using (for instance, on the include line)

```
@echo on
set INCLUDE=%INCLUDE%;"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include";
@echo off
pause
```